# Is it possible to create an snmp "proxy" agent?

Tags: c#, snmp, cacti

I have a situation when I have three computers A, B, C.

Computer A and B are on routable networks and can communicate with each other (different subnets). Computer C is not routable but is on the same subnet as B.

I want to monitor computer C from computer A using SNMP and cacti.

What I'm trying to write is an SNMP "Proxy" to sit on B which listens to a custom port and gets all requests made for SNMP from computer C.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any and all help.

Andrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't set up a UdpProxy on B that tunnels SNMP from the manager A to the agent C.

You'd use the .NET UdpClient class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx

I beleive SNMP uses two ports so you'd have to bind a UdpClient to those ports allow for receiving from the manager IP (and agent IP for Traps). Once you receive data you have to resend it to the agent IP and then send the response back to the manager. In the case of Trap messages (alerts/notifications from the agent) you'd have to send them to the manager.